# Trying to access doc info using object properties

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I'm making a CRUD app for adding college football teams to a database and retrieving data. I'm using Google Firestore for the database.

I'm able to retrieve a team's id and store it in a variable, but I'm running into issues using the id to retrieve the document, and then using object properties to get the info.

firebase.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';   
import { Team } from '../team.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(public db: AngularFirestore) {
  }

  getTeam(id:string) {
    return this.db.doc('teams/' + id);
  }
}
```

team-home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../shared/firebase.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Team } from '../team.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-team-home',
  templateUrl: './team-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./team-home.component.css']
})
export class TeamHomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
   private router: Router,
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private actRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  team = this.firebaseService.getTeam(this.id);

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

team-home.component.html

```
<p>
  {{team.schoolName}}
</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

team.model.ts

```
export class Team {
    id: string;
    schoolName: string;
    teamName: string;
    location: string;
    conference: string;
}
```

When I run the app and go to the page that displays the template, nothing shows except for the header from the app.component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the fetching data part code inside constructor or on ngOnInit()m otherwise code never get executed

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private actRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { 
  id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  team = this.firebaseService.getTeam(this.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I try this, I get the following errors:

`ERROR in src/app/teams/team-home/team-home.component.ts(25,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'id'.
src/app/teams/team-home/team-home.component.ts(26,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'team'.
src/app/teams/team-home/team-home.component.ts(26,46): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'TeamHomeComponent'.`